# How to understand runtime layout in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  layout :products_layout

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
    def products_layout
      @current_user.special? ? "special" : "products"
    end

end
```

Here when is method `products_layout` getting executed? There's nowhere I can see that calls the method `products_layout` so how could the symbol `:products_layout` be defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails has implicit rendering, so at the end of the method "show", since you haven't told Rails to do anything different, it will render the app/views/products/show.html.erb template.

In addition, it will look to see what layout you specified. here, you've given a symbol to layout, which Rails takes to mean "execute this method name to find out what layout I should use"

Comment: How do I pass `@current_user` back to the controller? It seems it's also not defined.

Comment: What are you using for authentication? Normally, that will be in the application_controller, and then accessible after.